# Grid overlay for designing in browser

Tags: browser, overlay

Does anyone know a grid overlay for designing in the browser and lining up elements? Preferably one where you can adjust to wrapper sizes from 1140px.

Comment: Ask a more specific question-  What does "designing in a browser" mean?

Comment: Edited but it seemed pretty obvious to me.

Comment: Nope, not obvious-  still a little unsure about what you mean.  Do you mean the end-user of your application will be moving elements around in the browser or are you talking about a tool that you as the designer will use to create a web page?

Comment: Maybe not to you but i've had loads of feedback on CSS tricks.

Comment: downvote for not answering the question and having a bad attitude...  good luck.

Comment: Just landed on this question from a search in DuckDuckGo. It seems a reasonably clear question to me. Shame it got closed because I'm sure there would have been more useful answers between 2012 and now. Wish Stack Overflow wasn't so close-happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean having an in-browser overlay, I just saw that the [Web Developer extension](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) for Firefox has the ability to display a grid overlay. Under the extension's `Miscellaneous` menu, there's a `Show Ruler` option. It seems like a pretty useful way to measure pixel sizes.